# Every time I update or install a plugin I get "Error Establishing a Database Connection in WordPress"

Tags: database

At first I thought it was a resource issue because I'm only using the lowest AWS ec2 instance, but now I think it might be something else.

I Google'd about a bit as it seems to be a common problem but couldn't find my issue, it only seems to happen when I update or install a plugin.

Rebooting my EC2 instance fixes the problem so either I have to upgrade my instance or it's a database issue.

Could someone point me in a direction on how to find out if it's a database error?

Comment: Do you have access to server logs?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Probably... the question is how do I access server logs?

Comment: I don't know. That is very server specific and I have never used EC2. You will need to ask your host.

Comment: Righty oh, brb. I am my host sooo I should find out ha.

Comment: Ok. You __are__ the host? That doesn't really make a lot of sense unless you are Amazon. What kind of access do you have and what OS does the server run?

Comment: @s_ha_dum It's a ec2 instance with ubuntu, I have root privileges, I've ssh'd in and I'm in my /var/log folder I can see mysql.err and mysql.log is that what I'm looking for?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12647/discussion-between-s-ha-dum-and-uzumakidev)